# how to automatically remove "Powered by ..." in Pelican CMS?

Tags: python, pelican

When generating content using Pelican, everything is Ok except that I see in the footer *"Proudly powered by Pelican ..."*

I want to get rid of it. I know I can remove it from the generated files manually, but that is tedious.

Is there a way to prevent the generation of the above phrase by asking Pelican to do that for me? Some magic Pelican command or settings, maybe?

Comment: Does the Pelican license allow you to remove that text?

Comment: @voodoo-burger see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41226345/344286 - Pelican doesn't insert that link, that comes from the theme.

Answer (score 4):

It all depends on which theme you are using.

You must be granted a permission to do that if you decide to publish your content. Check the license under which a given theme is distributed by its author. You can design your own theme though.

[SoMA](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican-themes/tree/master/SoMA/templates) theme, for instance, as the default theme,  uses `base.html` file which is inherited by other layout components using `{% extends "base.html" %}`.

```
<footer id="contentinfo" class="body">
    <address id="about" class="vcard body">
        Proudly powered by <a href="http://getpelican.com/">Pelican</a>,
        which takes great advantage of <a href="http://python.org">Python</a>.
    </address><!-- /#about -->
</footer><!-- /#contentinfo -->
```

You may find some other themes (actually I did not find on the ones hosted on GitHub), use an explicit `footer.html` file, search for it and modify at your will.

In all cases, there is no predefined magic pelican command that does what you want. That is done through the theme you choose to use.

Answer (score 3):

In your theme template, there will be a line like,

{% extends "!simple/base.html" %}

This base.html is used as the foundation for creating the theme. This file is available in : %PYTHON%\Lib\site-packages\pelican\themes\simple\templates

You can edit this file to remove the "Powered By.."

Answer (score 1):

It's part of the [theme](https://github.com/getpelican/pelican/blob/master/pelican/themes/simple/templates/base.html). Either modify it or choose another.

Answer (score -1):

Probably is not the answer you are looking for, but if you are already customizing the CSS, think about usgin CSS to hide the section.